# Infinite looping of failed Google Drive login

Tags: android, google-drive-api

My attempts to use the google drive on Android have been spectacularly unsuccessful. Initially I managed to get myapp working with the following client builder code.

```
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .setAccountName(email)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

I was able to create a file and save it on my drive. I then decided to try to use an app folder on Drive so changed the builder to look like this (added the SCOPE_APPFOLDER):

```
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .setAccountName(email)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

This resulted in an infintely looping 'Signing in...' page. Looking at my logging I see the following infinitely looping:

```
10-25 21:46:14.560  15349-15349/com.tcgcollection.tcgtrader D/TcgActivity﹕ GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{420d70e0: android.os.BinderProxy@422f88e8}}
10-25 21:46:15.835  15349-15349/com.tcgcollection.tcgtrader I/TcgActivity﹕ onActivityResult requestCode 1003 resultCode -1
10-25 21:46:15.860  15349-15349/com.tcgcollection.tcgtrader I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@420fc3c8 time:56012230
10-25 21:46:16.490  15349-15349/com.tcgcollection.tcgtrader D/TcgActivity﹕ GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{41be2df8: android.os.BinderProxy@422f88e8}}
10-25 21:46:17.645  15349-15349/com.tcgcollection.tcgtrader I/TcgActivity﹕ onActivityResult requestCode 1003 resultCode -1
10-25 21:46:17.740  15349-15349/com.tcgcollection.tcgtrader I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@420fc3c8 time:56014112
10-25 21:46:18.115  15349-15349/com.tcgcollection.tcgtrader D/TcgActivity﹕ GoogleApiClient connection failed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=PendingIntent{42023468: android.os.BinderProxy@422f88e8}}
10-25 21:46:19.075  15349-15349/com.tcgcollection.tcgtrader I/TcgActivity﹕ onActivityResult requestCode 1003 resultCode -1
```

My onConnectionFailed looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Utils.debug(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
    if (!connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
        return;
    }
    try {
        connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
        Utils.error(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity");
        Utils.exception(e);
    }
}
```

And the onActivityResult code looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Utils.info(TAG, "onActivityResult requestCode " + requestCode + " resultCode " + resultCode);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
            break;
```

If I comment out that single line requesting the extra scope then the program works again.

How can I get this code to work with the additional scope?

My gradle dependencies include:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
```